# How to create a simple python animation

Tags: java, python, animation

I need to create a little simulation of robots. That is, I would like to be able to create a simple GUI window with an x axis, y axis, and an image of a robot(s) (i.e., a dot), and I'd be able to animate it a bit - only set its (x,y) coordinates, and perhaps move it around by giving it a velocity and direction from the code.

It doesn't really matter what language I use - could be Java or Python or anything else.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I know this is a broad question. I'm looking for some general guidance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to learn something generally applicable from it, use (Py)OpenGl.

You can take apart my [SimPyLC robot example](http://www.qquick.org/educational.html) and learn from it. It's something I wrote for my students to learn about simple animations and real time controls that resemble a PLC (programmable logic controller)

It's small enough to dissect and completely understand.